# Converter int em str num laço for

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Gostaria que a variável do `input()` conservasse seu tipo `int` fosse somente convertida para `string` quando exclusivamente entrasse com o digito 's' para que eu possa sair do laço, sem mudar o `while`, existe alguma função que avalia ou trataria da forma como estou querendo?

```
import string
lista = list(string.ascii_lowercase[:6])
while True:
    for i,l in enumerate(lista, start=1):
        print(f"{i}. {l}")
    try:
        vm = int(input("Qual item deseja ou 's' para sair: "))
        if vm == 's':
          break  
    except IndexError:
        print("Tente um indice existente.")  
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Entre com uma opção existente.")
        break
```

Comment: Já pensou em ver se é igual a ```'s'``` antes de fazer a conversão? Se for ```'s'``` você faz o ```break```, senão efetua a conversão para ```int```?

Comment: De que forma? Porque poderia eu mudar o while x != 's', porém pretendo conhecer outra forma.

Comment: @AllanBelem A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Não faça a conversão até que seja necessário.

```
vm = input("Qual item deseja ou 's' para sair: ")
if vm == 's':
    break
vm = int(vm)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/ConditionalConversion.py).

Porém o mais correto é usar outra variável para guardar o valor convertido para `int`, só porque a linguagem permite não quer dizer que é sempre adequado mudar seu tipo. Reaproveitar a mesma variável para um objeto completamente diferente é um dos casos onde não é bom.

Comment: Exatamente, mas a vm passa a ser uma string, quero obrigar com algum tratamento a obedecer quando for somente uma string em exclusivo o 's', acredito eu que se é possível fazer uma comparação como essa  if vm.__str__(): seria possivel através de um tratamento.

Comment: Parece que você quer fazer algo errado, então aí complica, faça o certo e simples, fora o que eu falei o código está ótimo, não piore ele.